# multiple netlink interfaces in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver, ethernet

A user process can send a netlink message to the kernel by specifying destination's nl_pid to 0 (for kernel).
Suppose if there are two different kernel modules which have registered one netlink interface each. Then to which module does the user process's message will reach.
Does it reaches both or only one? Consider the below example.

Thanks in Advance.

```
struct sockaddr_nl src_addr, dest_addr;
...
...
dest_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
dest_addr.nl_pid = 0; /* For Linux Kernel */
dest_addr.nl_groups = 0; /* unicast *
...
...
msg.msg_name = (void *)&dest_addr;
msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(dest_addr);
...
...
printf("Sending message to kernel\n");
sendmsg(sock_fd, &msg, 0);
```

#### kernel module 1

```
static int __init module1_init(void)
{

sk1 = netlink_kernel_create(&init_net, NETLINK_USER, 0, module1_recv_msg,
                              NULL, THIS_MODULE);
if (!sk1)
  {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Error creating socket.\n");
    return -10;
  }
return 0;
}
```

#### kernel module 2

```
static int __init module2_init(void)
{

sk2 = netlink_kernel_create(&init_net, NETLINK_USER, 0, module2_recv_msg,
                              NULL, THIS_MODULE);
if (!sk2)
  {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Error creating socket.\n");
    return -10;
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you even create 2 netlink kernel sockets for the same family? You cannot because the socket port ids are same (0 is hardcoded for kernel in netlink handler file).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to omit the gory details and proceed directly to connector:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/connector/connector.txt

That's a "routable protocol" on top of netlink which does exactly what you want: routes netlink messages to various subscribers.

In general, netlink operates in terms of "families". Thus, netlink messages hitting port 0 (kernel) are dispatched on family field in the header. "Connector" above declares one such family with additional nested header to contain a family specific routing information.